# Knockout binding after double click event

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have created a js function that toggles the boolean value of a property on a object (located within an array. To summarize what I'm trying to do, I have 2 lists. One list shows the item if the boolean property is false. The other list will show an item if it is true (hence the toggle function).

My issue is when I'm tying the toggle function to a double click event (which triggers correctly, verified through the debugger) I can't seem to get the binding correct (or perhaps its another issue entirely). If I manually place the toggle function with a hard coded "Id" value (determines which item in the array is going to be toggled) the binding works correctly and the item appears in the 2nd list.

```
var TestNWJS = TestNWJS || {};

TestNWJS.QualificationList = (function () {

    //private functions
    function CreateQualificationModel(allCredentialsList) {
        TetsNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel = {};
        TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.AllCredentials = ko.observableArray(allCredentialsList);

    }
    function toggleselected(allCredentialsList, id) {

        var credential = ko.utils.arrayFirst(allCredentialsList, function (credential) {
            var stringToInt = parseInt(id);
            return credential.Id === stringToInt;
        });

        if (credential.Selected == false) {
            credential.Selected = true;
        }
        else {
            credential.Selected = false;
        }

        return credential;
    }

    //public function
    return {
        Init: function (allCredentialsList) {

            CreateQualificationModel(allCredentialsList);
            toggleselected(allCredentialsList, 51); // THIS IS THE HARDCODED TEST, IT WORKS 


            //THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO WORK CORRECTLY:
            $("#allCredentials").live('dblclick', function (e) { 
                toggleselected(allCredentialsList, this.value);
            });

            ko.applyBindings(TetsNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel);


        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle to understand what isn't working?  Also you are trying to add that from the view model, but I would suggest creating a quick custom binding handler to do this.  Also which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just to test this I did the following in a fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/pwkad/uend52s5/

```
$("#container").on('dblclick', function (e) {
    console.log('double clicked it');
});
```

By switching live to on it worked for me in the newest version of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing your code? Looking at the code you posted, looks like the value of Selected property is changing in the correct way. However, it´s not an observable, so you don´t have the result reflected on the screen.

Try create a class for each credential, and a observable 'Selected' property:

```
function Credential(id, selected)
{
   this.id = id;
   this.selected = ko.observable(selected);
}

TestNWJS.QualificationList.ViewModel.AllCredentials = ko.observableArray(allCredentialsList.map(function(item){ return new Credential(item.id, item.selected);}));
```

**Updated**

This is a codepen with a simple example. There is a viewmodel with a list of objects, each one with a observable property. There is a second computed property which filters only the selected items:

http://codepen.io/adilsonjr/pen/yygxbg

Comment: this would be within my viewmodel?

Comment: Yes. It should be within your viewmodel.